# recover information from outlook .oab files

Tags: outlook

Hey. I had part of my harddrive destroyed. I managed to successfully recover the all six .oab files and one "extend" file from my Outlook 2003 Application data folder.

I'm trying to deploy it on a new machine, but it seems that some registry key is required. Is there a way to deploy these files into a new outlook 2003? (or maybe 2007/2010, everything that words)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about Outlook used as a stand-alone email program, otherwise the data would be safe on the Exchange server anyway.

In this case, Outlook data is stored in .PST files, not .OAB ones: so, if you didn't manage to recover your .PST file(s), I'm sorry but you can't recover anything. If you have .PST files, you can simply open them from within Outlook and access whatever is inside.